# How can I create and save prefab at runtime?

Tags: unity

In Unity, how can I save prefab at runtime?

Suppose my Player can "place" object, how could I save them as prefab at runtime (but in debug/editor mode)?

Comment: Can you describe more of what kind of "saving" you need? Do you need to save it as an asset in your project folder that you can later use in the Unity Editor? Or can it save in memory for the duration of the game session, as an object the player can repeatedly place and re-place? Or does it need to save between play sessions in a built game, using local storage on the player's device? Or do you want to save to a server? Or some other case yet?

Comment: If your players aren't creating 3D meshes themselves, then you'll probably want to save the "data" of their placed object. Like the position, rotation, scale, color, and any other options you give the player. You could serialize all the data and write to a file or a web service, then fetch that data later and instantiate your object with all your saved data.

Comment: My player can put prefab on screen. I need to save that "group" of prefab in a single prefab ... Is it possible ?